# Expand chrome bookmark tree via Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is there a way to expand the bookmarks bar to a specific bookmark via javascript-Extension?

Let's say i have this Bookmark in my Bookmarks bar in google chrome: "Media/Music/Spotify(Page)" and want to expand the tree hirarchy until the spotify bookmark is clickable.

[Visual of what i am trying programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfR5O.gif)

so far i have found an API for that: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#method-search
but i can see no function to expand until a BookmarkTreeNode is reached.

> A node (either a bookmark or a folder) in the bookmark tree. Child
>   nodes are ordered within their parent folder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, you can't open the bookmarks bar from Javascript.  I don't believe you can even do that from within an extension, which is normally the last resort when attempting to manipulate the browser outside a web page.  Why do you want to do this?  There may be a better or more appropriate solution.

Comment: i would like to try writing an extension which keeps the bookmarks open after applying any action on them. there is a common (bug?) in chrome which closes the whole bookmark tree when you add/delete/mod a folder/bookmark.

my first attempt would have been to listen on events (of creation/deletion/modification/...) and then let my function expand the tree again until the modified bookmark is reached.

Comment: Okay, no - you're not going to do that.  Have a look at the myriad of bookmark manager type extensions that already exist - you'll see they all use the extension popup or a new tab.  If it is truly a bug then make sure to raise a bug report for Google (or they'll never know and it will never be fixed).